# SwiftUI macOS ScrollView crashes when HStack spacing is negative

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I am using the following code to create a horizontal scroll view with negative spacing (I'm using negative spacing so the items in the stack overlap). Whenever my app is in a small window and I interact with the scroll view's slider, the app crashes with a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)` error. Is this a known issue or is there a more correct way to implement this design?

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: -20) {
                ForEach(Array(elements.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, element in
                    Text(element.text).zIndex(Double(index))
                }
            }.frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add whts inside ForEach

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.1 / macOS 10.15.7. Which env did you use?